# Angularjs controller get the next three month third wed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am part of a group that every third Wednesday of the month, we meet. On the current site we manually put these dates in. In my angularJS controller I would like to get the next three meeting dates. I thought about a JSON file but again that is manual entry. Is there a way with pure JS to do this?

I have looked at http://momentjs.com/docs/ and http://www.datejs.com/ but I would like to do this in the controller and not a separate JS file.

Current site (http://cs.millersville.edu/~katz/lcac/) Look at the next meeting section. I currently manually enter those dates. I want to generate them on page load

Comment: Can you be more specific? It's hard to tell what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code to fetch third Wednesday of a month.

#### Logic:

```
1. Find what is the first day on the month.
2. Calculation: 14(day count of 2 weeks) - first day + 3(day count for Wed) + 1(to select Wed)
```

#### Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getThirdWeddate('8/20/2014')
});

function getThirdWeddate(inputDate){
    var date = new Date(inputDate);
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var monthStart = new Date(date.getYear() + 1900,date.getMonth(),1);
    var monthStartDayCount = monthStart.getDay();
    var dayInTwoWeeks = 14;
    var wedDayCount = 3;

    var thirdWedDate = parseInt(dayInTwoWeeks) - parseInt(monthStartDayCount) + parseInt(wedDayCount) + 1;
    var finalDate = new Date(date.getYear() + 1900,date.getMonth(), thirdWedDate);

    console.log(finalDate);
}
```

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I just found some code that was very similar to this. Thanks